# Pyfftw slower than matlab fft

Tags: python, matlab, fft, pyfftw

I'm trying to compare Pyfftw (in Python 3.6) with matlab r2017a fft.

```
import time
import numpy
import pyfftw
import multiprocessing


nthread = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
print(nthread)
n=2**20
a = pyfftw.empty_aligned(n, dtype='complex128')
print("fft_object = pyfftw.builders.fft(a)")
fft_object = pyfftw.builders.fft(a) #this instruction spend much time
print("generate numbers")
a[:]= 5*numpy.random.rand(n)
print(a)
print("start fft")
start = time.clock()
y=fft_object()
end4 = time.clock() - start
print(end, time:")
print(end4)
print("result")
print(y)
print(len(y))
```

while if i use matlab:

```
x=5*rand(2^20,1);tic;fft(x);toc
```

this request just the time for computation of fft algorithm, that is the approximatively the same time of the  python's call on fft_object().

Thanks in advance for your kind support.

Comment: So the Matlab call is just as fast as PyFFTW? Matlab uses FFTW as well, but they compile it with Intel MKL accelerations. If you don’t have Intel’s C compiler or MKL library, your PyFFTW is likely going to be slower than Matlab’s FFT.

Comment: The `pyfftw.builders.fft` step takes a long time because by default FFTW is finding an optimized FFT scheme by actual measurement: see https://hgomersall.github.io/pyFFTW/pyfftw/builders/builders.html#additional-arguments especially the `planner_effort` flag. You can use `export_wisdom` to export this measurement to a file, and and `import_wisdom` to load it, saving you a lot of time. Matlab tells FFTW to quickly `estimate` which FFT scheme to use, because Matlab users can’t be troubled to create a plan and deal with wisdom… 

Comment: Can you update the question and include the output times of both Python & Matlab?

Comment: You should also use `threads` in the builder.

Comment: Ok,Yes  Matlab call is just as fast as PyFFTW . Could you provide me an example pythone code for my needs? thanks in advance for your kind support.

Comment: @AhmedFasih a quick FYI, the [default behaviour is changed in master](https://github.com/pyFFTW/pyFFTW/pull/148) to use `FFTW_ESTIMATE`.

Comment: @HenryGomersall thanks for the note, and thanks for your hard work on PyFFTW! It’s stupendous <3

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at GPU-based codes (if you have the proper hardware):

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyfft

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.cuda

They are based on PyCuda und PyOpenCL. I don't have much experience with these so you have to do a little digging to find what suits you best.